# Neo4j Batch update of data

Tags: neo4j

How can I do multiple Nodes update in neo4j cypher?

Now I'm trying to do like this:

```
MATCH (user151325288158:User{userId:151325288158}),
      (user88245:User{userId:88245}) 
SET user151325288158.balance=2902833.4219789803 
SET user88245.balance=146701.0299999991 
RETURN user151325288158.balance,user88245.balance;
```

But here I have problem that if such user is absent in DB, nobody will be updated.
Other problem is performance, such queries are slow.

Is there some method to do such bulk updates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have pairs of `userId`s and new `balance` values in an array of maps/dicts, like this:

```
[
    {
      "userId": 151325288158,
      "balance": 146701.09
    },
    {
      "userId": 887436512344,
      "balance": 22453.34
    },
    {
      "userId": 873927654232,
      "balance": 300002.22
    }
]
```

You can pass this array as a parameter to a Cypher query to `MATCH` on the `userId` and update the `balance` property like this:

```
WITH {data} AS pairs
UNWIND pairs AS p
MATCH (u:User) WHERE u.userId = p.userId
SET u.balance = p.balance
```

Comment: what will the query if i want to add new userId and balance in the same query

Answer (score 2):

By following [William Lyon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2954199/william-lyon)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38150002/2891028), I was able to implement a batch update of ***multiple properties*** as follows:

```
UNWIND [{id: 123456, name: "John", age: 27}, {id: 789012, name: "Jane", age: 24}] AS updateUser
MATCH (user: User)
WHERE user.id = updateUser.id
SET user += updateUser
RETURN user
```